# how to group this relationship in the laravel?

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am trying to group users by date that is in the relationship accesses and page this result.

Model User

```
public function acessos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Acessos::class,'id_usuario');
}
```

Model Acessos

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'id_usuario');
}
```

Livewire component

```
$data = User::query()
            ->search($this->search)
            ->with('acessos')
            ->has('acessos')
            ->paginate($this->perPage);

return view('livewire.relatorios.acessos.acessos-component',[
             'data' => $data
         ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the user() method from Acessos Model and change the hasMany() method to belongsToMany in User model's acessos method. This Will solve your problem.

Remove this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'id_usuario');
}
```

And change this:

```
public function acessos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Acessos::class,'id_usuario');
}
```

Comment: i try but returns error : SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name,  $data = User::with('acessos')->paginate(10);

Comment: try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/73065/descriptionmicrosoftodbc-sql-server-driver-sql-ser.html